# Headless BPM Solutions for Integration with Custom application for workflow management

Tags: architecture, business-process-management, ibm-bpm

Are there any BPM solutions that can integrate with a Custom application so that I can use BPM only for the workflow and UI from my application

Answer (score 1):

Many of the BPM engines out there will support this. The right one likely depends on the stack you are comfortable with.  The first I would look at would be [Camunda](https://camunda.com), which is java based (not that your app has to be java based to use it).

I've seen some customers make progress with [Flowable](https://flowable.com) as well, but I'm not as familiar with the ins / outs of that.  However there are tons more out there, the "right" one for you would depend on having a much better understanding of your environment, the systems involved, how much you want the business users participating / owning the process etc.

Sorry that there isn't an "easy" button we can hit and get you set up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Drux, I know there is no "Easy" button :)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the open source process orchestration engines can do this.  Another example is [ProcessMaker](https://github.com/processmaker). As long as the the solution is 100% API driven, then most engines have trended towards completely headless support.  You will want to stay away from the legacy solutions as they tend to be quite bloated.  ProcessMaker is probably the lightest weight solution of the bunch